# How to Continue a Command after Error in Batch Files?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

So here's the code

```
cd C:\Users\%USERNAME%
G:
md backup
cd backup
c:
xcopy *.* /e /h g:
pause
```

While the Xcopy is trying to copy certain files it runs into an error, and stops copying, how do I force it to skip the current file and copy the next one?

Comment: `xcopy /?` is your friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the below switch to continue copying even if there is an error.

> /c

**Usage**

```
xcopy *.* /e /h /c g:
```

All switches can be viewed here.

[Microsoft - Xcopy](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true)